# Success stories from Play! Framework?

Tags: playframework

I'm evaluating the Play! Framework for my company. We're actually thinking about using it as spring's small brother (basically for "smaller enterprise projects"). Up to now, we use Grails there, but are rather irritated by it's bad integration with maven and a lot of strange effects that come of it's dynamic nature.

However, I cannot find an article anywhere from someone who as actually *created* a project using Play! (I know, on the website, they tell you some websites that use it, but that does not really help).

Has anybody actually seen an article describing how it was using Play! as application framework?

Answer (score 16):

The Google Groups has a number of people who have notified of their project launch. There have been a number of people who have expressed the ease and joy of developing with the PlayFramework.

I myself have built a number of small applications for statistical analysis of one of our internal applications, and I am also in the process of building a much larger site. The simple answer, is that Play just makes life of a coder easier, more rewarding and gives instant feedback (through the real time compilation and in browser errors).

There are a few blogs of people's findings of Play, and you will see plenty of [retweets](http://twitter.com/playframework) of people who have launched successful applications with Play.

If you are looking for guidance on whether it is the right choice for your business, then it really depends on your business. Play is young, is still growing, but it is a great framework. If you have the opportunity to try it out on a small project, then do so. I very much doubt you will regret it.

EDIT: 2011 Update

I thought I would add a brief update, because a new blog post has been written giving someone's experience and success story using Play, and i thought it would be useful.

http://blog.davejafari.com/experiences-developing-with-play?c=1

Comment: The link in your answer is dead.

Comment: Here's a working link: http://blog.davejafari.com/post/49266223574/experiences-developing-with-play

Answer (score 8):

I do exactly what you're asking. I work for a pharmacy chain and our heavy lifting is done with Spring MVC but I use Play! to write smaller internal applications all the time. One of the greatest things about play is when my boss comes to me about needing a new app I have it up and off the ground in an hour.

One application I did allows our pharmacists to double check cash prescription prices by bouncing the drug and quantity off our central databases. Another one sets up an interface where our quality control people can enter SQL queries, save them, schedule them to run, and then have the results emailed to them. They use this to find various statistical outliers.

We also have a fairly complex social network written in Spring MVC that I will be porting to Play! throughout 2011. The network is for our pharmacists and pharmacy techs to collaborate about prescription compounding and whatever else they want to talk about.

Finally, I'm in the process of finishing up a B-to-B app between a large third party prescription buying group and our pharmacy chain. I can't go into detail about it because the contracts are not finalized but it will be nationwide and pretty high load. The scheduling was very aggressive and without Play! it wouldn't have been possible. See that's the best thing about Play!, even if you outgrow it you can prototype and get something live very fast.

Comment: I hope you can blog about it pretty soon

Comment: After two years passed from your answer, what are your thoughts about play framework today?

Answer (score 5):

Here is an [article by Peter Hilton](http://www.lunatech-research.fr/archives/2010/06/14/how-demo-play-framework-live-coding-script), one of the contributors to the play framework, detailing a five-minute live-coding Play demo.

Also on the play framework site itself, there is a detailed walk-through of [how to create a blog](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/guide1), from scratch, using Play! Framework.  Someone also rewrote the same article but using [scala rather than java](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.1/scguide1).

Answer (score 5):

I worked on a project at a large global Insurer that implemented an Insurance Quoting Engine in Play. Took about 3 months which is about a year less than a similar project that was done in GWT.

We deployed to Tomcat, integrated with WebSphere MQ, used [NTLM via Jespa](http://www.ioplex.com/) and slicked up the UI with [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/).

Answer (score 3):

In google-groups was one entry where someone told that he wrote a facebook-app, with 1.000.000 Hits per month, so it shows that you can use it in great projects.

I'm unsure what exactly you want. 
About grails and maven: Play and Maven is difficult too, at least there are a lot of mails in the google-group about it. However, since 1.2, there is better Maven support. You can add Maven dependencies directly from conf/dependencies.yml. There are probably some restrictions, but it works well in general.

Comment: Honestly, for really performance intensive purposes, a million hits a month is *nothing*. That's well under 1 hit per second. Sustain a million hits a day on one web server and one DB and that's more interesting.

Answer (score 2):

I'm writing twitter like service with comment and group options. http://pleap.com/

Comment: is that using play? I don't think so.

Answer (score 2):

I'm currently working on an analytics project using play! and I must say that play! is one fine choice if what you're looking for is performance. It can handle heavy load and lots of requests much faster than RoR. And using it is very simple even if you don't know java ! Totally like this framework.

Answer (score 1):

I am using Play with Scala, AppEngine and I love it. You might want to look into SammyJS.org, super easy js framework for the client side.
http://geeks.aretotally.in/mind/2011/1/14/play-framework-scala-gae-sammy-in-production.html

Comment: I didn't know you could use play with scala module con gae... do you know any tutorial?

Comment: When I went to this page a trojan tried to attack my pc. Steer clear, people.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.playapps.net/ is written in play, you could ask at play's google group about it

more over, play is used by the play core team to develop real life applications...