# play framework 1.2.4 vs 2.0 for production

Tags: playframework

I plan to use Play Framework to build a production ready application in 3 months. Should I begin with 1.2.4 or 2.0. 2.0 has some very nice features but it's in beta.

Any advice will help.
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The advice from the core development team is that Play 1.2.x is still the best way to develop applications for production. Play 2.0 is due for release around the time your application is due for production, but it will be the first release, so there is likely to be bugs etc. Also,  2.0 is very much a work in progress. It is capable of building complete applications (as seen by the samples provided in the distribution) but there are still features missing, and things are liable to change between now and the release candidate. I therefore would be wary about basing a live application around it yet.

All that said, if you are building in Scala for Play 1.2.4, I believe the upgrade path to 2.0 is likely to be relatively straightforward, so that may be your best option.

Comment: what are some features that are missing is 2.0 but are in 1.2.4?

Comment: at this stage, I think most of the core features are now included, but are unlikely to be as mature as Play 1.2.4. If you follow the discussion on the google groups site, you will see that many people are actively using it. Some are getting on fine, but there is lots of debate, and issues....it really depends on your use case as to whether it is soon enough to make the jump

Answer (score 11):

**UPDATE July 2012:**

Play 2 matures from day to day so I needed to update...

- if you want proven stability and lots of plugins: Stick with the 1.X Branch.
- if you want to live on the edge: Go with the 2.X Branch.

If you go with Play 2 keep the following in mind:
Even though Play 2 is as of writing 2.0.2 some things like sending email are still missing and planned for a later release. Many plugins need to be updated and tested with play2. The documentation is getting better but it is still not as mature as the 1.X branch.

KR :)

---

To make it short:

**Stick with 1.X***

- At the moment there is a lot going on in the master branch of play 2.0 and the beta is already outdated by far. Things like file uploads are missing, a proper documentation or the crud module are missing and the whole framework needs to be shaped. If you want to go productive soon then use the current production version. If your app is more for self enlightenment go ahead and experiment with version 2.

Answer (score 0):

Needless to say, it is now more than a year since the question was posed and I believe you could safely choose Play 2 for a production app today.

Comment: Are you speaking from experience, or is this just an assumption?

Comment: @SharpC: I did an app in Play 2, yes. Didn't have any issues. Did you see http://stackoverflow.com/q/4344721/309483 ? And http://typesafe.com/company/casestudies